# Debugging Nodejs V8 in VIM

Tags: node.js, debugging, vim

Is there currently an option to debug v8 in vim?

In v8 they deprecated old options --debug and --debug-brk and node-vim-debugger doesn't seem to know the new protocol..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following adhoc solution (read "hack"):

```
nnoremap <C-D> Odebugger<esc>:w<CR>:!node debug node_modules/nodeunit/bin/nodeunit -t dev<CR>dd:w<CR>
```

If you have that in your vimrc, pressing Ctrl + D would launch a script which does the following:

1. `O`Go to insert mode in a new line
2. `debugger<esc>:w<CR>` insert a debugger statement and save the file.
3. `!node debug node_modules/nodeunit/bin/nodeunit -t dev<CR>` launch the program (in my case, I use nodeuint and I have written a test code that runs it).
4. `dd:w<CR>` these commands are run after the process is closed, they remove the `debugger` statement, leaving your file exactly as you

Comment: Thanks for sharing, the solution is interesting :-) I am still in webstorm for this reason

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit old, but searching for a solution myself I've found this: https://github.com/eliba2/vim-node-inspect .
Looks in development, but I can successfully connect and debug my docker containers with it.